# Set ggplot theme through a variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I change the theme using a variable?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length,Petal.Width))+
  geom_point()
```

I could do

```
ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length,Petal.Width))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw()
```

instead what if my theme is defined in a variable,

```
var1 <- "theme_bw"
var2 <- "theme_grey"
```

Can I use this to set the theme?

Comment: `ggplot() + get("theme_bw")()`

Comment: That works. Thanks! Would you like to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Theme <– "theme_bw()"    
eval(parse(text=as.character(Theme)))
```

This is another way to do it since I got errors when I used get.

Comment: This method worked for me, whereas ```get()``` generated an error message.

Answer (score 3):

```
ggplot() + get("theme_bw")()
```

Posting `baptiste`'s answer above as I didn't want this question to remain unanswered.